# Prisma not generating field in WhereInput for an array of strings

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

I've been using GraphQL for probably 8 or so months. I've never run into a problem like this before. When I make a change in my datamodel, and run the command which generates a prisma file. I have an existing field in a table which's type is an array of strings, so `languages:[String!]`. However, in my generated prisma file, I do not see an option to query on `languages` in my table.

This is not an issue of prisma not generating an update to the file. I have deleted it and it generates the same thing. Furthermore, `languages` is present in other generated types, just not the `ItemDescriptionWhereInput` (table name is ItemDescription). Lastly, this field is currently in use, I've updated this field in my API and it works fine. So this seems to be a prisma issue, not something related to my code.

Here is my ItemDescription table:

```
type ItemDescription {
    id: ID! @unique
    item: ItemData! @relation(name: "ItemDescriptionToItemData")
    languages: [String!]
    description: String
    shootDates: String
    location: String
    productionCompany: String
    assetSource: String
    assetUsageMotion: String
    assetUsageStill: String
    talentUsage: String
    earliestStart: String
    earliestEnd: String
    generalNotes: String
}
```

Here is the Where input that gets generated by prisma, notice the missing `languages` here:

```
input ItemDescriptionWhereInput {
  """Logical AND on all given filters."""
  AND: [ItemDescriptionWhereInput!]

  """Logical OR on all given filters."""
  OR: [ItemDescriptionWhereInput!]

  """Logical NOT on all given filters combined by AND."""
  NOT: [ItemDescriptionWhereInput!]
  id: ID

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  id_not: ID

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  id_in: [ID!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  id_not_in: [ID!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  id_lt: ID

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  id_lte: ID

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  id_gt: ID

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  id_gte: ID

  """All values containing the given string."""
  id_contains: ID

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  id_not_contains: ID

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  id_starts_with: ID

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  id_not_starts_with: ID

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  id_ends_with: ID

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  id_not_ends_with: ID
  description: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  description_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  description_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  description_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  description_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  description_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  description_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  description_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  description_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  description_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  description_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  description_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  description_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  description_not_ends_with: String
  shootDates: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  shootDates_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  shootDates_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  shootDates_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  shootDates_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  shootDates_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  shootDates_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  shootDates_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  shootDates_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  shootDates_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  shootDates_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  shootDates_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  shootDates_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  shootDates_not_ends_with: String
  location: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  location_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  location_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  location_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  location_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  location_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  location_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  location_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  location_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  location_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  location_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  location_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  location_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  location_not_ends_with: String
  productionCompany: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  productionCompany_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  productionCompany_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  productionCompany_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  productionCompany_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  productionCompany_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  productionCompany_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  productionCompany_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  productionCompany_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  productionCompany_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  productionCompany_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  productionCompany_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  productionCompany_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  productionCompany_not_ends_with: String
  assetSource: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  assetSource_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  assetSource_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  assetSource_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  assetSource_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  assetSource_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  assetSource_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  assetSource_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  assetSource_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  assetSource_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  assetSource_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  assetSource_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  assetSource_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  assetSource_not_ends_with: String
  assetUsageMotion: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  assetUsageMotion_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  assetUsageMotion_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  assetUsageMotion_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  assetUsageMotion_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  assetUsageMotion_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  assetUsageMotion_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  assetUsageMotion_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  assetUsageMotion_not_ends_with: String
  assetUsageStill: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  assetUsageStill_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  assetUsageStill_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  assetUsageStill_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  assetUsageStill_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  assetUsageStill_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  assetUsageStill_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  assetUsageStill_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  assetUsageStill_not_ends_with: String
  talentUsage: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  talentUsage_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  talentUsage_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  talentUsage_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  talentUsage_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  talentUsage_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  talentUsage_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  talentUsage_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  talentUsage_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  talentUsage_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  talentUsage_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  talentUsage_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  talentUsage_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  talentUsage_not_ends_with: String
  earliestStart: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  earliestStart_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  earliestStart_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  earliestStart_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  earliestStart_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  earliestStart_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  earliestStart_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  earliestStart_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  earliestStart_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  earliestStart_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  earliestStart_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  earliestStart_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  earliestStart_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  earliestStart_not_ends_with: String
  earliestEnd: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  earliestEnd_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  earliestEnd_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  earliestEnd_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  earliestEnd_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  earliestEnd_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  earliestEnd_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  earliestEnd_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  earliestEnd_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  earliestEnd_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  earliestEnd_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  earliestEnd_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  earliestEnd_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  earliestEnd_not_ends_with: String
  generalNotes: String

  """All values that are not equal to given value."""
  generalNotes_not: String

  """All values that are contained in given list."""
  generalNotes_in: [String!]

  """All values that are not contained in given list."""
  generalNotes_not_in: [String!]

  """All values less than the given value."""
  generalNotes_lt: String

  """All values less than or equal the given value."""
  generalNotes_lte: String

  """All values greater than the given value."""
  generalNotes_gt: String

  """All values greater than or equal the given value."""
  generalNotes_gte: String

  """All values containing the given string."""
  generalNotes_contains: String

  """All values not containing the given string."""
  generalNotes_not_contains: String

  """All values starting with the given string."""
  generalNotes_starts_with: String

  """All values not starting with the given string."""
  generalNotes_not_starts_with: String

  """All values ending with the given string."""
  generalNotes_ends_with: String

  """All values not ending with the given string."""
  generalNotes_not_ends_with: String
  item: ItemDataWhereInput
}
```

Also to prove this has nothing to do with prisma not updating my generated file, here's another type that prisma generated from this same table `ItemDescription`

```
input ItemDescriptionUpdateWithoutItemDataInput {
  description: String
  shootDates: String
  location: String
  productionCompany: String
  assetSource: String
  assetUsageMotion: String
  assetUsageStill: String
  talentUsage: String
  earliestStart: String
  earliestEnd: String
  generalNotes: String
  languages: ItemDescriptionUpdatelanguagesInput
}
```

So my question is, why is prisma not generating a whereinput that includes a value with a type of array of strings? I have no way to query on this now.

Comment: Yep it even seems like it doesnt generate this for any basic types like `string` or `int` which makes having these types completey useless if you have an array, whats the point of having data you cant query? Good job prisma. Now I have to redo the work to make a new table just to hold a string so I can actually query it.